# SUPEE 8788 not being applied properly on Magento CE 1.9.0.1

Tags: magento-1.9, security, patches, supee-8788

I've just tried to apply the new SUPEE 8788 patch to my magento 1.9.0.1 but it came up with several errors:
I ran the following command in SSH in the magento root directory:

```
bash PATCH_SUPEE-8788_CE_1.9.0.1_v1-2016-10-11-06-57-03.sh
The errors started with this, all the way at the top.
Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully...
ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully.
```

Throughout the patching process it came up the following 79 times:

```
Hmm...  The next patch looks like a unified diff to me...
The text leading up to this was:
```

In total, 3 hunks failed:

```
Patching file skin/adminhtml/default/default/media/uploader.swf using Plan A...
No such line 2 in input file, ignoring
Empty context always matches.
Hunk #1 failed at 0.
1 out of 1 hunks failed while patching skin/adminhtml/default/default/media/uploader.swf
Hmm...  The next patch looks like a unified diff to me...
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
Patching file skin/adminhtml/default/default/media/uploaderSingle.swf using Plan A...
No such line 2 in input file, ignoring
Empty context always matches.
Hunk #1 failed at 0.
1 out of 1 hunks failed while patching skin/adminhtml/default/default/media/uploaderSingle.swf
Hmm...  The next patch looks like a unified diff to me...
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
Patching file skin/adminhtml/default/default/xmlconnect/boxes.css using Plan A...
Hunk #1 succeeded at 88.
done
```

According to the MageReport, the patch failed.
I have no idea how to fix these errors and I **need some help with fixing what went wrong.**

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue.

A possible fix would be to **edit the patch file and remove the lines affecting the binary SWF files.**

After that run the patch and delete manually the following files:

- `skin/adminhtml/default/default/media/flex.swf`
- `skin/adminhtml/default/default/media/uploader.swf`
- `skin/adminhtml/default/default/media/uploaderSingle.swf`